# Angular stuck after stylesheet is selected

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

```sh
$ ng new my-app

? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
```

Nothing happens after this. It just stuck and not even ctrl c or ctrl z working. I have to terminate the terminal.

I am using Windows 10,
Angular CLI: 12.2.5,
Node: 14.17.6,
Package Manager: npm 7.23.0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can find your answer here. You should probably create a new issue in the angular CLI GitHub repo